# HTML dropdown from a JSON string

Tags: html, json, twitter-bootstrap, select

I have a **JSON string** that looks like this

```
[
    {
     "offset":1,
      "result":
             [
              {
                "host":"x.x.x.x",
                 "count":"123"
               }
             ]
           },
    {"offset":2,"result":[{"host":"y.y.y.y","count":"1123"}]}
]
```

I want to populate a **dropdown select** in HTML to show me only the list of "host" from the **JSON string**. Im already using bootstrap framework. is there a way to do it in bootstrap? if not jquery?

Comment: You can't do it with CSS, and therefore not with bootstrap itself. Also note there a `"` missing before `123"` for the `count`-entry.

Comment: @Peanut thats a typo...corrected.

Comment: @SunilPachlangia i want to populate a select tag with all the values corresponding to the key "host" in the JSON data.... how can i do it in jquery

Comment: do you have your json string in PHP or in JS? It is a little bit less information to help you. And please accept the fact that this is not a "please write the code for me" plattform. You should try it by yourself or at least show us what you have already tried.

Comment: @steven my json is in php. im populating it via api call .

Comment: @SunilPachlangia it is a valid JSON...according to  JSONLint

Comment: so parse the json into an array, walk through the array and create option tags for each entry. Sourround it by a select tag and print the html code to your site. This should be a big thing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `parseJSON` for this

**HTML Code**

```
<div>
   <select id="showDrop">
       <option value="">Select One</option>
    </select>    
</div>
```

**Script to use this json data**

```
var jsonData = '[{"offset":1,"result":[{"host":"x.x.x.x","count":"123"}]},{"offset":2,"result":[{"host":"y.y.y.y","count":"1123"}]}]';

var obj = $.parseJSON( jsonData );

var dropOption = '<option value="'+obj[0].result[0].host+'">'+obj[0].result[0].host+'</option><option value="'+obj[1].result[0].host+'">'+obj[1].result[0].host+'</option>'

$('#showDrop').append(dropOption);
```

Working [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q55b06db/1/)

Answer (score 0):

here's the simple implementation of the same json in javascript and bootstrap

HTML

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">
    Dropdown
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1" id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var json = [
    {
        "offset":1,
        "result":
             [
              {
                "host":"x.x.x.x",
                 "count":"123"
               }
             ]
    },
    {
        "offset":2,
        "result":
            [
                {
                    "host":"y.y.y.y",
                    "count":"1123"
                }
            ]
    }
];
var htmlStr = "";
json.forEach(function(x){
    var li = '<li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">' + x.result[0].host +' </a></li>';
    htmlStr += li;
});

$('#list').html(htmlStr);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jigardafda/p4x8mke2/

Comment: this works :)....thanks. but how would u point the var json to a php file that generates the JSON? instead of having it in the source code ?

Comment: `<?php
  $ar = array('apple', 'orange');
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var json = <?php echo json_encode($ar) ?>;
  alert(json);
</script>`  something like this you can do.

sample code - https://gist.github.com/jigardafda/d72fcdc3e832f2aadb75#file-gistfile1-php